# How to properly format a page in Microsoft Word for the whole document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to do an quite "individual" design of my document with MS Word (2016). That's what I imagined:

```
       |
       |    
       |      //the left line for the complete page and is a dashed line
<~2cm> |      
       |      //some content over here
       |
       |
```

For the right side I thought about a menubar-style where I can adjust the "content", I thought about the following:

[image: Sidebar table of contents]

I would adjust it myself so there is not need for it to be like the "real" table of content. What I am looking for now is a possibility to adjust the right/left side for all pages of the document while I still need to be able to modify the "chapter 1, chapter 2...." sidebar for each side. Now this is easy with PowerPoint, since I could use the Master to adjust the pages. Sadly there seems to be nothing similar for MS Word, right?

What I did now was using Word's "side edges"-function, which got me the dashed line on the left (sadly I can only configure it up to 31pt while I would like to have ~2cm which would make ~56pt).

Now I would like to add graphics which are displayed on each side. How can I do this? Or is there even another, better way to do what I would like to do?

Comment: Word really is not the tool for this. You may be able to accomplish this in Publisher though...

Comment: @LPChip That's right, Word is not a good tool for that, but I have no idea what is a good tool for it tbh. TeX seems to do some fancy stuff and you could probably also acquire the goal in it, but I cannot imagine that there is no tool that could do exactly what I want, since it is nothing too innovative nobody has ever heard of. I could also set up an A4-Format of PP ...  I never actually heard of Publisher, I'm going to have a look at it. Thanks :)

Comment: Publisher, also by Microsoft, is similar as Word. But where Word is primarily made to write books, Publisher has lots of graphical options, and is aimed at designing newspapers